# Google Analytics 4 - Connect to unlimited properties with Service Account

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are having an issue where our service account configured for Google Analytics 4 (GA4) is limiting the amount of properties to which we associate it in order to retrieve data.

Is there a way to be able to a associate the service account to unlimited properties or a different way to connect through the API to be able to list and retrieve information for all properties within the same account?

Thank you!

We tried associating new properties to the service account until we got the following error:
[Error we are getting when associating the user to a new property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIlt8.png)

Answer (score 0):

A user can have access to a limited number of accounts this is true for service accounts as well.

Last I heard the number was in the hundreds im surprised you are hitting it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In our case we have over 700+ active clients so we are easily reaching that limit. Do you know a workaround for a situation like this on how to connect through the API and access the properties data?

Comment: your clients should be granting you access via oauth2 and you can store the refresh token.    Service account should be used for accounts you the developer own.